# can't figure out which css property is being applied/inherited

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using some components from twitter bootstrap css and have combined into a custom css file.

I'm using mostly the components relating to the toolbar and have setup a toolbar.

I've applied the following additional css, but for .signinbox_left: hover for some reason, the hover box is much much larger than the surrounding li. I've tried alsorts of combinations of margins and padding and height to get this to work, but there seems to be some css property that is being applied that i  cannot fathom. Furthermore, i dont know how to override this property.

Here is the hosted example: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3417415/Toolbar/toolbar.html

Here is the css that isnt working the way intended. Hover over "create account" to see what i mean.

```
.signinbox_left :hover{

    background-color: red;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
    border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px;

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried it without the border? Could be padding it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Remove the float and the position.

```
.signinbox_left:hover{

  background-color: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
  border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px;

}
```

Notice there is no space between the class and the :hover.

Comment: That fixed it thank you. The space between the class and hover was also affecting things. Thank you for helping me out. This has been driving me nuts for the last few hours.

Answer (score 0):

using SRWare Iron (Chrome, really) inspector, I see that element has the dimensional metrics `padding: 10 10 11 4`.

In the css there's a definition for `.topbar div > ul a, .nav a` with the actual definition `padding: 10px 10px 11px;` (toolbar.css line 14). disabling that line makes the element shrink appropriately.

I'd start with that .topbar definition.